# Place Order Redirects to Cart Page in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I got issue that, while i place the order while saving order it redirects to Cart Page and order is not saved, while debugging this i got erro log that,

```
    There has been an error processing your request

    From Header set twice

    Trace:
    #0 /home/buyusape/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(438): Zend_Mail->setFrom('sales@buyusapep...', 'Owner')
    #1 /home/buyusape/public_html/app/code/community/Ebizmarts/Mandrill/Model/Email/Template.php(68): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send('sales@buyusapep...', 'Owner', Array)
    #2 /home/buyusape/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(532): Ebizmarts_Mandrill_Model_Email_Template->send('sales@buyusapep...', 'Owner', Array)
    #3 /home/buyusape/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Data.php(221): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('checkout_paymen...', 'general', 'sales@buyusapep...', 'Owner', Array)
    #4 /home/buyusape/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(528): Mage_Checkout_Helper_Data->sendPaymentFailedEmail(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote), 'Gateway error: ...')
    #5 /home/buyusape/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
    #6 /home/buyusape/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
    #7 /home/buyusape/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #8 /home/buyusape/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #9 /home/buyusape/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #10 /home/buyusape/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #11 {main}
```

Can  anybody help me how to resolve thsi please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using SMTP Pro in magento, and while i press Run Test button, i get above error too. How to resolve this.

Comment: ok i once had the issue similar and just a simple re-indexing of tables helped, however if the issue persist try checking your email templates too.

Comment: Hi Munjal Thanks for reply, but re-indexing doesn't helped. but i solved this error by changing template.php of Email. since there were setFrom() 2 times used. so, i modified that file. and checked evything line by line i got that this error solved, Get Mail sent successfully but no mail received by costomer or admin, that mean magento is not firing any mail.